# Script to delete Access rows based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, scripting

I have an access table that list all my SQL instances, and for licensing purpose I want to delete the least expensive rows of multiple instances leaving only one row per server name:

```
Server Name     Instance Name  SQL Server Edition

Server1         MSSQL          Standard
Server1         SQLEXP         Express
Server2         MSSQL          Developer
Server3         MSSQL          Enterprise
Server3         SQLSt          Standard
```

Would output

```
Server Name     Instance Name  SQL Server Edition

Server1         MSSQL          Standard
Server2         MSSQL          Developer
Server3         MSSQL          Enterprise
```

Comment: How do you know which ones are the least/most expensive?  Do you have any table or column indicating the cost?

Comment: I know by the SQL Edition column Enterprise>Standard>Developer>Express>unkown.  In most cases we only have one instance per server, but in some cases we have multiple instances per server, and I would like to auto delete the least expensive (based on server edition) row for multiple instances per server.